# Trying to make a multiple valued list results in error

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a list that takes 2 parameters in classes Program.cs and Game.cs. In Program.cs I am doing this: (The error is being given under game which is saying: Game does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.
   `List<Game> JoinLists = new List<Game>();
    JoinLists.Add(new Game("Elf", 6));`

In-Game.cs I have this written:

```
public class Game
{
    private string _type;
    private int _strength;

    public void JoinLists(string charType, int strength)
    {
        this._type = charType;
        this._strength = strength;
    }
}
```

Comment: constructors must have the same name as the class they reside in, change   `public void JoinLists(string charType, int strength)` to  `public Game(string charType, int strength)` and you should be fine. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructors must have same name as the class:

```
public class Game
{
    private string _type;
    private int _strength;

    public Game(string charType, int strength)
    {
        this._type = charType;
        this._strength = strength;
    }
}
```

and no return in the signature.

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Answer (score 1):

Your error is pretty self explanatory `Game does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments`, it means that you should add the constructor with 2 arguments, obviously

```cs
public class Game
{
    private string _type;
    private int _strength;

    public Game(string charType, int strength)
    {
        this._type = charType;
        this._strength = strength;
    }
}
```

From [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors)

> A constructor is a method whose name is the same as the name of its
>   type. Its method signature includes only the method name and its
>   parameter list; it does not include a return type.

You can also omit `this` pointer, because your class fields and constructor arguments have the different names, there is no need to qualify them using `this`

Answer (score 0):

create a constructor

```
public Game(string charType, int strength)
{
   // code here
}
```

Or you can change the create `Game`

```
List<Game> JoinLists = new List<Game>();
JoinLists.Add(new Game().JoinLists("Elf", 6));
```